# Expand dataframe columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Say I have a data.frame or data.table of the following form:

```
df <- data.frame("date"=c("2012-11-07", "2012-11-07", "2012-11-08", "2012-11-08", "2012-11-06", "2012-11-06"),
                 "id"=c(1,2, 1, 2, 2, 1),
                 "val"=c(100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105))
```

I like to expand this so that each `id` gets its own column containing the `val` that goes with a given `date`, i.e. it should take the form

```
df.new <- data.frame("date"=c("2012-11-06", "2012-11-07", "2012-11-08"),
                     "1"=c(105, 100, 102),
                     "2"=c(104, 101, 103))
```

Does a method exist for data.frames or data.tables that can do this?

Comment: `dcast.data.table` or, if you are a masochist, base `reshape`.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = val, names_prefix = 'X')
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  date          X1    X2
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 2012-11-07   100   101
2 2012-11-08   102   103
3 2012-11-06   105   104
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dcast.data.table(df,date~id, value.var="val")
         date   1   2
1: 2012-11-06 105 104
2: 2012-11-07 100 101
3: 2012-11-08 102 103
```

Answer (score 1):

With dcast:

```
dcast(df, date ~ id)

  date        1   2
1 2012-11-06 105 104
2 2012-11-07 100 101
3 2012-11-08 102 103
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  df[with(df, order(date, id)), ],
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "date",
  timevar = "id"
)
```

which gives

```
        date val.1 val.2
6 2012-11-06   105   104
1 2012-11-07   100   101
3 2012-11-08   102   103
```